# Where do I find CodenameOne's version of iKVM?

Tags: codenameone, ikvm

I need to do some research if/how to use backend code from some already available Java web service in some newly created Windows 10 UWP app. The Java code deals with parsing special binary data, depends on things like configuration files and some additional 3rd party libs like Apache Commons*. The current ideas are either providing some native DLL to be bundled with the UWP-app or providing a stand-alone one publishing some high level web services which the UWP-app consumes.

I came across iKVM and CodenameOne and read that iKVM itself is not maintained anymore, but CodenameOne forked a version for their own purposes. At various places authors say that that version of iKVM is managed in the official GitHub repo of CodenameOne, but I'm unable to find it there. The only thing I find are some helper implementations and formerly committed DLLs in the repo-history and such, but nothing which looks like the complete forked project.

Any idea where I can find this? Obviously I'm missing something...

I would simply like to have a look at what CodenameOne needed to change, how much effort they put into keeping up with Java 8, what of those efforts went back to the original project etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that. I was under the wrong impression that the code resided in the `Ports/UWP` directory but apparently it isn't there. I'm probably the person who wrote that in those places...

We added a link to the actual repo there for reference. It's here: https://github.com/shannah/cn1-ikvm-uwp